# Igusa-Clebsch invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, reference-request

I am looking for a good reference for definitions and basic properties of the Igusa-Clebsch invariants for curves of genus $2$ (especially, but not only, in positive characteristic).

Comment: Edited only to add the reference-request tag.  Note that except in characteristic 2 the invariants of a genus-2 curve are also the invariants of a binary sextic (= homogeneous sextic in two variables up to linear coordinate changes).

Comment: Have you read Igusa's original paper? I think it's pretty readable except it's not written in scheme language.

Comment: Which paper of Igusa should I read?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Arithmetic Variety of Moduli for Genus Two". 

Comment: Is there any good book in which it is written something about Igusa invariants?